# TSQL Insert rows with incrementing primary key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I am attempting to populate rows into SQL Server 2008 table, I want to know how I can increment the primary key to look at max number then add one. The table is not auto populating/incrementing the PK column.

I will be using the values option to insert the rows so need something I can use in there. Any ideas/code would be appreciated.

This is the code and error;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblAnalysisType ON

INSERT INTO 
[Keystone_KSI].[dbo].[tblAnalysisType]
([intAnalysisClassID],[vchAnalysisTypeDesc],[numRateAdjustment],[numRepeatAdjustment],[intParentTypeID],[chrRank],[intUpdateUserID],[dteDateUpdated])
VALUES(26,'20-10-0000-1001', 1.00,1.00,NULL,NULL,30,'05/04/2016 15:41:00'),
(26,'20-10-0000-1021', 1.00,1.00,NULL,NULL,30,'05/04/2016 15:41:00');
GO

### SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblAnalysisType OFF

Msg 545, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'tblAnalysisType' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what an `IDENTITY` column does?  What specifically have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: In addition to David's comment you should not even consider trying to do this yourself. There are so many pitfalls of MAX(ID) + 1 you can't list them all here. The beauty of identity is all the pain has already been worked out.

Comment: You should show efforts taken by you to solve your problem. Please include code as a work you have done so far to solve your question.

Comment: You don't have a single accepted answer.  You do know the check mark means accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IDENTITY data type or you can use [Sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) which give you IDENTITY type functionality with a bit more flexibility and possibilities.

Comment: Sql Server 2008 hasn't Sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You really should use Identity but

```
insert into table (pk, col1, col2) 
select max(pk) + 1, 'value1', 'value2' 
from table
```

I think this will cover the first row but not sure

```
insert into table (pk, col1, col2) 
select isnull(max(pk), 0) + 1, 'value1', 'value2' 
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

So. You can use identity, but if your table has aleready column with identity you won't.

You have to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE MoqSequence
(
   SeqName VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL, SeqValue INT NOT NULL
)
```

And function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_GetSeqValue
(
 @seqName VARCHAR(512)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
 -- Declare the return variable here

 UPDATE MoqSequence
 SET SeqValue = SeqValue + 1
 WHERE SeqName = @seqName;

 DECLARE @value AS INT = (SELECT SeqValue FROM MoqSequence WHERE SeqName = @seqName);

 RETURN @value;

END
GO
```